# Password Protected Pages Don't Accept A Valid Password After Changing The Password

Tags: cache, password, debug

I have a password protected page which I recently was asked by my client to change the password. The password protection is done from the WordPress dashboard by using the Status and visibility option from Page-> PageName -> Edit option and selecting Visibility: Password Protected and editing the password. The previous password had worked fine for many months but once I changed the password, the new password was not accepted. I keep getting the prompt for the password no matter how many times I enter the correct password.

**Cache busting or a clue?**

Interestingly if I add a cache busting querystring like ?a=0 to the end of the protected page's URL, I am let in! What's up with that? Does the page/WordPress know that I previously entered the correct password?

With WordPress, does the user need to enter the password each time they visit the password protected page or only the first?

**Here are the installed plugins:**

**Akismet Anti-Spam**

Activate | Delete
Used by millions, Akismet is quite possibly the best way in the world to protect your blog from spam. It keeps your site protected even while you sleep. To get started: activate the Akismet plugin and then go to your Akismet Settings page to set up your API key.

Version 4.1.4 | By Automattic | View details

**Aweber Forms by Optin Cat**

Add New Optin Form | Support | Deactivate
Aweber Optin Cat Helps You Get More Email Subscribers. Create Beautiful Campaign Monitor Opt-In Forms In Less Than 2 Minutes.

Version 2.4.1 | By Fatcat Apps | View details

**BackWPup Pro**

Deactivate
WordPress Backup Plugin

Version 3.7.0 | By Inpsyde GmbH | Visit plugin site | Documentation

**Beaver Builder Plugin (Agency Version)**
Activate | Delete
A drag and drop frontend WordPress page builder plugin that works with almost any theme!

Version 2.3.0.2 | By The Beaver Builder Team | Visit plugin site

**Boxzilla**

Deactivate
Call-To-Action Boxes that display after visitors scroll down far enough. Unobtrusive, but highly conversing!

Version 3.2.22 | By ibericode | View details

**Contact Form 7**

Settings | Deactivate
Just another contact form plugin. Simple but flexible.

Version 5.1.7 | By Takayuki Miyoshi | View details

**Easy Google Fonts**

Settings | Deactivate
A simple and easy way to add google fonts to your WordPress theme.

Version 1.4.4 | By Titanium Themes | View details

**Easy Media Download**

Activate | Delete
Easily embed download buttons for your digital media files

Version 1.1.4 | By naa986 | View details

**Elementor**

Settings | Deactivate
The most advanced frontend drag & drop page builder. Create high-end, pixel perfect websites at record speeds. Any theme, any page, any design.

Version 2.9.8 | By Elementor.com | View details | Docs & FAQs | Video Tutorials

**Elementor Pro**

Deactivate
Elementor Pro brings a whole new design experience to WordPress. Customize your entire theme: header, footer, single post, archive and 404 page, all with one page builder.

Version 2.9.3 | By Elementor.com | Visit plugin site | View details | Changelog

**Google Analytics for WordPress by MonsterInsights**

Activate | Delete
The best Google Analytics plugin for WordPress. See how visitors find and use your website, so you can keep them coming back.

Version 7.10.4 | By MonsterInsights | View details

**Hello Dolly**

Deactivate
This is not just a plugin, it symbolizes the hope and enthusiasm of an entire generation summed up in two words sung most famously by Louis Armstrong: Hello, Dolly. When activated you will randomly see a lyric from Hello, Dolly in the upper right of your admin screen on every page.

Version 1.7.2 | By Matt Mullenweg | View details

**Jetpack by WordPress.com**

Activate | Delete
Bring the power of the WordPress.com cloud to your self-hosted WordPress. Jetpack enables you to connect your blog to a WordPress.com account to use the powerful features normally only available to WordPress.com users.

Version 8.4.2 | By Automattic | View details

**ManageWP - Worker**

Activate | Delete
We help you efficiently manage all your WordPress websites. Updates, backups, 1-click login, migrations, security and more, on one dashboard. This service comes in two versions: standalone ManageWP service that focuses on website management, and GoDaddy Pro that includes additional tools for hosting, client management, lead generation, and more.

Version 4.9.6 | By GoDaddy | View details

**Master Slider**

Deactivate
Master Slider is the most advanced responsive HTML5 WordPress slider plugin with touch swipe navigation that works smoothly on devices too.

Version 3.5.8 | By averta | View details

**MC4WP: Mailchimp for WordPress**

Activate | Delete
Mailchimp for WordPress by ibericode. Adds various highly effective sign-up methods to your site.

Version 4.7.6 | By ibericode | View details

**MOJO Marketplace**

Activate | Delete
This plugin adds shortcodes, widgets, and themes to your WordPress site.

Version 1.5 | By Mike Hansen

**One Click Demo Import**

Deactivate
Import your content, widgets and theme settings with one click. Theme authors! Enable simple demo import for your theme demo data.

Version 2.5.2 | By ProteusThemes | View details

**OptinMonster API**

Deactivate
OptinMonster is the best WordPress popup plugin that helps you grow your email list and sales with email popups, exit intent popups, floating bars and more!

Version 1.9.6 | By OptinMonster Team | View details

**Pro WP Limit Login Attempts**

Settings | Deactivate
Limit rate of login attempts and block ip temporarily . It is protecting from brute force attack.

Version 2.6.3 | By Arshid | Visit plugin site

**Recent Posts Widget With Thumbnails**

Deactivate
Small and fast plugin to display in the sidebar a list of linked titles and thumbnails of the most recent postings

Version 6.7.0 | By Martin Stehle | View details

**Riddle Quiz Maker**

Deactivate
Create 14 types of quizzes, personality tests, surveys, and more on Riddle.com - then use our plug-in to easily embed them into any page or post.

Version 4.2.0 | By Riddle Technologies AG | View details

**Smush**

Settings | Docs | Upgrade | Deactivate
Reduce image file sizes, improve performance and boost your SEO using the free WPMU DEV WordPress Smush API.

Version 3.6.1 | By WPMU DEV | View details | Rate Smush | Support | Roadmap

**Sucuri Security - Auditing, Malware Scanner and Hardening**

Activate | Delete
The Sucuri plugin provides the website owner the best Activity Auditing, SiteCheck Remote Malware Scanning, Effective Security Hardening and Post-Hack features. SiteCheck will check for malware, spam, blacklisting and other security issues like .htaccess redirects, hidden eval code, etc. The best thing about it is it's completely free.

Version 1.8.24 | By Sucuri Inc. | View details

**W3 Total Cache**

Activate | Delete
The highest rated and most complete WordPress performance plugin. Dramatically improve the speed and user experience of your site. Add browser, page, object and database caching as well as minify and content delivery network (CDN) to WordPress.

Version 0.13.2 | By BoldGrid | View details

**WooCommerce**

Activate | Delete
An eCommerce toolkit that helps you sell anything. Beautifully.

Version 3.9.1 | By Automattic | View details

**WooCommerce Blocks**

Activate | Delete
WooCommerce blocks for the Gutenberg editor.

Version 2.5.11 | By Automattic | View details

**WP File Manager**

Buy Pro | Donate | Deactivate
Manage your WP files.

Version 6.4 | By mndpsingh287 | View details

**WP Retina 2x**

Deactivate
Make your website look beautiful and crisp on modern displays by creating + displaying retina images.

Version 5.6.0 | By Jordy Meow | View details

**WPForms**

Activate | Delete
Beginner friendly WordPress contact form plugin. Use our Drag & Drop form builder to create your WordPress forms.

Version 1.5.6.2 | By WPForms | Visit plugin site

**WPForms AWeber**

Activate | Delete
AWeber integration with WPForms.

Version 1.2.0 | By WPForms | Visit plugin site

**WPForms Conversational Forms**

Activate | Delete
Create Conversational Forms with WPForms.

Version 1.3.0 | By WPForms | Visit plugin site

**WPForms Form Abandonment**

Activate | Delete
Form abandonment lead capture with WPForms.

Version 1.2.0 | By WPForms | Visit plugin site

**WPForms Surveys and Polls**

Activate | Delete
Create Surveys and Polls with WPForms.

Version 1.4.0 | By WPForms | Visit plugin site

Comment: **A quick tip for getting great answers**: Many experts are busy people. Help them get to all the facts as soon as possible (without asking follow up questions such as "how does this password system of yours work?") and you will get many more answers. Check [our guide to asking good questions](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) if you need to.

Comment: @MatthewBrownakaLordMatt I updated the description of the problem. I described how the password is set using the built-in WordPress functionality and added a list of the installed plugins.

Comment: Caching is, to me anyway, clearly the issue.  If the caching plugin does not have a method to clear the stored page then you'll need to wait for it to expire.  Depending on your hosting environment, there may be additional caches to clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**RESOLVED!**

See that **Sucuri** plugin?

The DNS for my site points to a Sucuri server which does caching.

I logged into the Sucuri site and added an exclusion for the WordPress password protected page to the caching setup using the UI. Now the new password works and the page behaves as expected. No cache busting required.

The login page posts to a PHP file which hashes the entered password, stores it in a cookie and sets its expiration date to 10 days in the future so you can visit the password protected page for 10 days until you will be prompted for the password again. This is assuming that you are accessing the page from the same device and browser.